# Flash game about growing a base of alien blobs to fight intruders

Tags: story-identification

I’m looking for a flash game, probably made in the mid-2000’s, about growing an army of these small alien blobs to fight off waves of intruding blobs. It has a 2D top-down art style.

You hatch these little alien blobs and feed them to keep them alive. The blobs start off as eggs, hatch as babies, and grow larger as they mature. I *think* they also become old and die eventually, but I’m not completely sure about that.

There are waves of enemies spawning that your blobs have to defeat. This provides resources to grow and raise more blobs.

If I remember correctly, the game has one static map that the playfield takes place in. It’s an alien world and there’s a circular area in the corner in the shape of a crater to keep your eggs before they hatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the game - it's called [Micro Life](https://www.albinoblacksheep.com/games/microlife). I did misremember one detail - resources come from clicking on eggs your micro creatures lay, not from defeating enemies.